# Gitlab Artifacts ERROR: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... forbidden

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, http-status-code-401, artifacts

coming across an issue when using artifacts for the first time. The issue is visible when the CI runner tries to upload an artifact:

```
ERROR: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... forbidden  id=1698 responseStatus=403 Forbidden status=403 Forbidden token=xxxxxx
FATAL: permission denied                           
ERROR: Build failed: exit status 1
```

I'm using the Omnibus package on Ubuntu 14.04 - latest version installed. Artifacts are enabled in the Admin section, setting the file size to 100MB and in the gitlab.rb config:

```
## Build Artifacts
gitlab_rails['artifacts_enabled'] = true
#gitlab_rails['artifacts_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/artifacts"`
```

Output of `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info`:

```
System information
System:         Ubuntu 14.04
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   2.3.1p112
Gem Version:    2.6.6
Bundler Version:1.13.6
Rake Version:   10.5.0
Sidekiq Version:4.2.1

GitLab information
Version:        8.14.5
Revision:       6f43aa0
Directory:      /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter:     postgresql
URL:            https://githost.net
HTTP Clone URL: https://githost.net/some-group/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@githost.net:some-group/some-project.git
Using LDAP:     yes
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:        4.0.3
Repository storage paths:
- default:      /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories
Hooks:          /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:            /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git
```

There isn't much in the logs - the production log just shows the POST request to .../artifacts.

any ideas?

Comment: Same here, could you solve your problem?

Comment: No, did a reinstall and did a backup and restore of repos. Real PITA.

Comment: I'm seeing similar error messages in a public project I occasionally contribute to. But with a cleartext `token`. Should the maintainers be worried about the latter?

Comment: I have the same issue. Any new about this?

Comment: In my case it was a proxy misconfiguration (in the GitLab CI variables).